# Adding JSON content to PSCustomObject - The property cannot be found on this object

Tags: json, powershell, pscustomobject

Quite new to objects in PS.

I'm trying to create pscustomobject, adding JSON contents to it via ConvertFrom-JSON and then I'm trying to get contents from another JSON to be set on one of the properties ( nested hierarchy)

```
$combinedObject=@()
$props = @{
     ServiceDefinitions = @()
     DataCenters = @()
 }

$combinedObject = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props
$servicedefinitions = Get-ChildItem -Path .\ServiceDefinitions\ | Select Name
$datacenters = Get-ChildItem -Path .\DataCenters\ | Select Name
$environments = @("Production")
$env="TEST"
  Foreach ($datacenter in $datacenters)
  {
    $datacenterdata = $null
    write-host "new run"
    write-host $datacenter.Name
    $datacentername = $datacenter.Name
    $datacenterdata = Get-Content -Path .\DataCenters\$datacentername\config.json -Raw
    $datacenterformatteddata =  $datacenterdata | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 5
    $combinedObject.DataCenters += $datacenterformatteddata
    $combinedObject.DataCenters.$datacentername
}

Foreach ($datacenter in $datacenters)
  {
  $pods = $null
  $datacetnername = $null
  $datacentername = $datacenter.Name
  $pods = Get-ChildItem -Path .\DataCenters\$datacentername\$env\Pod\ | Select Name
  Foreach ($pod in $pods)
  {
    $podname = $pod.Name
    $poddata = Get-Content -Path .\DataCenters\$datacentername\$env\Pod\$podname\config.json -Raw
    #echo $combinedObject.DataCenters
    write-host $datacentername
    $podformatteddata =  $poddata | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 5
    $combinedObject.DataCenters.$datacentername.pods += $podformatteddata
  }
}
```

For each loop iterations I receive

```
The property 'pods' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

I can query the pods but cannot set it, it looks to be of a system type System.Object[] do I need to convert it somehow to PSCustomObject for the contents of the next JSON file to be added to it?

Comment: does this ```$combinedObject.DataCenters.$datacentername``` have a property called 'pods'?

Comment: correct, I can see it when I call It $combinedObject.DataCenters.$datacentername its of a type System.Object[]

Comment: at least with the posted code that can't be. the varibale ```$combinedObject``` contains a object with 2 properties (ServiceDefinitions, DataCenters) - that's it... each of those properties are arrays, where you fill in data.... what happens if you do $combinedObject.DataCenters[0].pods = "anything"?

Comment: $combinedObject.DataCenters += $datacenterformatteddata a set of values are added under $combinedObject which results in   $combinedObject.DataCenters.ExampleA.pods being there.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by changing JSON from
pods:[] to

```
podlist:{ pods:[]}
```

and referencing

```
  $combinedObject.DataCenters.$datacentername.podlist.pods
```

to set the value.